# MaskedTextBox restrict characters to hexadecimals - A-F0-9

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to customize MaskedTextBox so that it will allow user to input text in specific format:
 `__ __ __ __ __ __` where each underscore can be valid hexadecimal character (A-F and 0-9).

Currently I've set mask property to: `>AA AA AA AA AA AA`, this gives me correct format (six groups of two characters separated by space) and I've added `KeyDown` event:

```
private void maskedTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.D0:
        case Keys.D1:
        case Keys.D2:
        case Keys.D3:
        case Keys.D4:
        case Keys.D5:
        case Keys.D6:
        case Keys.D7:
        case Keys.D8:
        case Keys.D9:
        case Keys.NumPad0:
        case Keys.NumPad1:
        case Keys.NumPad2:
        case Keys.NumPad3:
        case Keys.NumPad4:
        case Keys.NumPad5:
        case Keys.NumPad6:
        case Keys.NumPad7:
        case Keys.NumPad8:
        case Keys.NumPad9:
        case Keys.A:
        case Keys.B:
        case Keys.C:
        case Keys.D:
        case Keys.E:
        case Keys.F:
        case Keys.Left://navigate
        case Keys.Right://navigate
            return;
        default:
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            break;
    }
}
```

This restricts characters to those I want.

After that I've started to search how can validate input on paste (same way normal MaskedTextBox does - by removing invalid characters).However I started thinking I'm reinventing wheel here.

Maybe there is a better way to customize MaskedTextBox? Ideally I'd like to set mask to 
 `>HH HH HH HH HH HH` which should restrict characters to valid hexadecimals (I'm aware this isn't possible by current implementation)

Can I extend MaskedTextBox with custom characters in mask? Ideally I'd like to add support for `H` as hexadecimal character.

Comment: Well, this opens some questions for you to answer. For example, what do you want to do if the user pastes invalid characters? Do you simply want to strip them away, or replace them with a specific value, or do you want to prevent the paste operation altogether, or...?

Comment: @LucMorin I've already mentioned that in my question - same way normal MaskedTextBox does - by removing invalid characters.

Comment: Why the down vote? I think this is a valid question. I clearly pointed what I need, what have I tried. I'll be grateful for pointing me why someone thinks my question deserves that vote.

Comment: I don't know about the downvote, but back to "removing invalid characters", the thing is that the MTB will not let you enter invalid characters. It will not "remove" them, so when you come with a string to paste into it containing invalid characters, you simply want to strip them? That will make the input look weird now, won't it?

Comment: @LucMorin but this is how MTB works. If You set mask to `00 00 00` then copy `123ab12` and try to pase it into MTB You will get `12 31 2` in it. I'm thinking about same behavior. Everything except A-Z0-9 should get removed